# Send SMS when mobile device comes out of a specific area

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I am building a android application which
1.Tracks phones location using GPS and stores it a file
2. It sends a SMS to a number when the phone goes out of a specified area.

I've implemented the first one using commonsware's `Locationpoller` but I want to know how to implement the second one.

How do I select a specific area on Map ?
How to create a alarm(or event) when phone is out of that area ?

Comment: Read GeoFencing tutorial..

Answer (score 1):

To implement

`It sends a SMS to a number when the phone goes out of a specified area.`

you can decide the radius of say for e.g. 5km relative to your current location on map. now you have the current location store it in shared preference. implement [The Service](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html). Use [Location Listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html). so when the [onLocationChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html#onLocationChanged%28android.location.Location%29) is called, you [can calculate the distance](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D%29) between the new location and location stored in shared preference. if it exceeds your decided area, then send the sms.

may it works.

**EDIT**: since your man refuses to post any code, I found some. Here's how to [send a text message programmatically](http://www.allappsdevelopers.com/TopicDetail.aspx?TopicID=43948ae6-ab67-413b-a65c-e765aac7192d), with Android 2.2 and above, if you have trouble figuring out where your user is, I'll write something up for you to crib off of as well:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button btnSendSMS;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
       btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new 
       View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
        sendSMS(System.getProperty("numberToSendTo"), “Hello my friends!”);
           }
       });
    }
    //---sends an SMS message to another device---
    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
    }
   }
```

Comment: @hd1 this is just one way to go, if you know how to implement service in android and how to use location listner, shared preference and calculating the distance between two geo points, you can manage to implement all this togather.

Comment: In general, code is provided with answers on here... That's why I commented.

Comment: @hd1 that will be too long over here, so i've provided all the required links.

Comment: It's too long to paste a link?

Comment: @hd1 the problem is how to detect the specific area on the map, and not just how to send the sms.

Comment: That's a [points inside polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) problem. Solved long ago, mate.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to specify geographical areas:

Some common scenarios:

1) The most simple: a circle with center and radius.
2) Axe-parallel rectangle
3) a (closed) polygon

For all of them you
 
- Store the coordinates of that ares as latitude/longitude coordinate pairs.

From Gps fix to fix you check the `isIside(area)` state; when it changes from outside to inside it is an "EnterArea", if it changes from inside to outside it is an LeaveArea.
Once you detect a LeaveArea you send the SMS.

What remains is how to calculate the `isInside(area)`:

For circle: inside = `if (distanceMeters(currentPoint, circleCenter) <= radiusMeters)`
For rectangle: each mobile plattform has a point in rectangle method.
For polygon: use a pointInPolygon() from internet.

For inside rectangle and polygon: You can calculate with the original GPS (WGS84) coordinates.
For inside circle: `distanceMeters`. Each plattform provide a methof to calculate the distance between two lat/long coordinates.